# Installing pdftotext library on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pdftotext

pdftotext library is a requirement in requirements.txt. While trying to push to heroku, I get the following error:

```
remote:          Running setup.py install for pdftotext: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for pdftotext: finished with status 'error'
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-rnbekz45/pdftotext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o0if2tl3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
remote:              warnings.warn(msg)
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            running build_ext
remote:            building 'pdftotext' extension
remote:            creating build
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
remote:            gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=0 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.6m -c pdftotext.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pdftotext.o -Wall
remote:            pdftotext.cpp:3:10: fatal error: poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h: No such file or directory
remote:             #include <poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h>
remote:                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:            compilation terminated.
remote:            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-rnbekz45/pdftotext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o0if2tl3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rnbekz45/pdftotext/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Normally I'd solve this by installing `libpoppler-cpp-dev` with `apt`. But on heroku, I don't have root access to do that. Is there a solution for this?

I realize that strictly speaking, this isn't a programming question. But I need this to deploy my program, so I hope the purists here do forgive me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [How do I install additional software packages that my application requires?](https://help.heroku.com/IYRYW6VB/how-do-i-install-additional-software-packages-that-my-application-requires):

> We don't offer official support for installing extra packages but there are a couple of unsupported options.
>
> One is the experimental [heroku-apt-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). You can use this by including any APT package in an `Aptfile` in your application. The buildpack will then install these packages on the dyno when you deploy your application.

So, to do this, first add the build pack:

```sh
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
```

Then, create an `Aptfile` in your source directory with the following contents:

```
libpoppler-cpp-dev
```

And deploy as you normally would. Let me know if that helps!